# Why aren't there any first-order sentences which have the property of being true in all non-standard models of PA and false in the standard one?

Tags: first-order-logic, higher-order-logic, nonstandard-models

I'd like to know where the following result comes from (that is, whether there is a more general result from which it follows or else how it can be proven):

There is no first-order sentence which is true in all non-standard models of arithmetic but false in the standard one, whereas there are second-order sentences which have this property.

(I've found this briefly stated in the wikipedia article on Nonfirstorderizability)

Help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Best,

Berta

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $\varphi$ be any sentence that is false in the natural numbers. Let theory $T$ be first-order Peano arithmetic with $\lnot\varphi$ as an added axiom. Then $T$ has a model, the natural numbers. Thus by the Lowenheim-Skolem Theorem, $T$ has models of arbitrarily high cardinality, and in particular models other than $\mathbb{N}$. The sentence $\varphi$ is not true in such a model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I suppose what answers my question is then that Löwenheim-Skolem holds for first-order theories but not for second-order ones. Am I right?

Comment: That's one way of viewing it. For your second-order question, one would have to refine the question, since second-order PA is categorical.

Comment: I am looking into the notion of categorical axiomatization. And I still don't see how the question could be refined. It seems that for a categorical theory, Löwenheim-Skolem simply does not hold. I need to learn more about it, but if you don't mind, could you say something as to how you would refine the question? Thank you!

Comment: To produce non-standard models where quantification over *sets* of natural numbers is allowed, one needs to extend the language of PA to take in at least some fragment of set theory.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\varphi$ be a sentence that is true in all non-standard models of arithmetic but false in the standard model.

Then the theory T constructed by adding $\neg \varphi$ to Peano's axioms has a unique model; the standard model of arithmetic.

Thus, every  statement $P$ in the language of number theory is either true in every model of $T$ or false in every model of $T$. In particular, Gödel's completeness theorem implies that every such $P$ is provable or disprovable: $T$ is *complete*.

Our axioms for $T$ are recursively enumerable, so Gödel's first incompleteness theorem implies $T$ must be *incomplete*: thus we get a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't understand how the second step is justified. From the fact that $\phi$ is true in all non-standard models of arithmetic does not seem to follow that by adding its negation to PA we get a theory that has as model the natural numbers. Obviously I'm missing something, but it seems to me that this new theory could, for instance, not have any model at all. Could you elaborate on it a bit more?

Comment: Ah, your assumption was that $\varphi$ was false in the standard model but I forgot to repeat that in my post. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand this fact, see George Boolos, [Logic Logic and Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/067453767X) (1998), page 57 :

> [Consider the formula : ]
>
> (C) $\quad \exists X(\exists x Xx \land \forall x \forall y[Xx \land (x = 0 \lor x = y+1) \rightarrow x \ne y \land Xy])$.
>
> [It] is a sentence that is true in all nonstandard models of arithmetic but false 
>   in the standard model [footnote : To see that (C) is true in any nonstandard model, take as $X$ the set of all nonstandard elements of the model. $X$ is nonempty, does not contain $0$, hence contains only successors, and contains the immediate predecessor of any of its members.]
>
> To see that it is false in the standard model, suppose that there is some suitable set $X$ of natural numbers. $X$ must be nonempty: if its least member $x$ is $0$, let $y = 0$; otherwise $x = y + 1$ for some $y$. Since $x$ is least, $y$ is not in $X$, and "$Xy$" is false.

For [non-standard models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model_of_arithmetic) of first-order $\mathsf {PA}$, see George Boolos & John Burgess & Richard Jeffrey, [Computability and Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521701465) (5th ed - 2007), page 304 :

> To sum up: the elements of the domain of any nonstandard model $\mathcal M$ of arithmetic
>   are going to be linearly ordered by LESS THAN. This ordering will have an initial
>   segment that is isomorphic to the usual ordering of natural numbers, followed by a
>   sequence of blocks, each of which is isomorphic to the usual ordering of the integers
>   (negative, zero, and positive). There is neither an earliest nor a latest block, and
>   between any two blocks there lies a third. Thus the ordering of the blocks is what
>   was called [...] a dense linear ordering without endpoints, and so, it is isomorphic to the usual ordering of the rational numbers.

*Added*

Assuming that we have convinced ourselves that the formula (C) is *true* every *non-standard* model but *false* in $\mathbb N$, if we assume that (C) is expressible in *first-order* logic, we can use it as the formula $\varphi$ of Hurkyl's answer and the conclusion follows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is great to have a particular example of second-order sentence which is true of all non-standard models and false of the standard one. However, I don't see how this explains why this cannot hold for first-order sentences.

Answer (score 1):

> Why aren't there any first-order sentences which have the property of being true in all non-standard models of PA and false in the standard one?

There [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/202497/12490) a set of sentences with the property that all sentences are true in all non-standard models of PA, but infinitely many are false in the standard one:

$\omega \neq 0$, $\omega \neq \sigma(0)$, $\omega \neq \sigma(\sigma(0))$, ...

For these formulas to be sentences, $\omega$ must be a constant and part of the signature $S=\{\sigma,0,\omega\}$.